# iOS Build Refused by Apple related to bitcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, bitcode

### Here is the email form Apple:

Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "[MyApp]". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Invalid Bundle - The app cannot be processed because of a fault in the bitcode bundle generation. The problem has been resolved in Xcode 7.3 and later versions. Rebuild the app with the latest Xcode and resubmit to the App Store.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team

---

The thing is we are already using latest Xcode (8.3).

The archive works and the upload to iTunesConnect without errors.

But the build doesn't appear and we get the email above form Apple.

It looks like the issue happens when Apple processes the build, unfortunately we have absolutely no logs of what is happening :/

Itunes connect is not very helpful neither :

### [image: iTunes Connect builds]

Is anyone facing the same issue ?

Comment: Are you using bit code in your project? If you are not using remove the check mark while generating the build. If you are using bit code means, cross check all of the libraries and frameworks you are using also bit code enabled.

Comment: Yes we are indeed using bitcode in the App and all of our dependencies. I also checked in the generated XCArchive thanks to `otool -l AFramework.framework/Aframework | grep __LLVM` and they all seem to have bitcode section. This issue happened following the Xcode update (swift 3.1) ...

Comment: restart xcode. clean.. re-build test and try to upload again.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, Xcode 8.3.2, the app contains frameworks built with _Carthage_ 0.23.0. This worked fine before the update to Xcode 8.3.